# How to make a directive for adding sections in angular at runtime based on attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have many sections like

And Accordingly i have different code  maintained in their html files like home.html and about.html and want to make a angular custom directive to render at runtime

And i had tried for making a directive but it works only first time not when i am using multiple times . so need help for making this directive

```
app.directive('mysection', function() {
return {
   restrict: 'E',
   transclude:true,
   templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
       return "sections/"+attrs.templateUrl +".html"
   }
}
});
```

And in html i am writing

```
<mysection template-url="headerSection"><mysection>
<mysection template-url="headerSection"><mysection>
```

Comment: You have no gain in using directives there. 

Consider using ng-include instead until your "sections" deserve to be treated as directives or to be supported by a controller.

Comment: hi alex ,i know this can be achieved using ng-include

Comment: but i want to make a directive for this for future needs of my project

Answer (score 0):

try this markup

```
<mysection template-url="headerSection"></mysection>
<mysection template-url="headerSection"></mysection>
```

Note the close tag

Comment: It should work. Please see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gKXs9NPTT5QT0Z7za94G?p=preview. I copied your code there and modified it slightly

Comment: as my html files are in a folder named as sections

Comment: check the location of your "sections" folder. Must be relative to the root folder. Run the app and check the url being requested in the Network tab in the Developer Tools in your browser of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex referring to your code i had reached to the solution

```
app.directive('mysection', function() {
return {
   restrict: 'E',
   templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
       return attrs.folderName+"/"+attrs.templateUrl +".html"
   }
 }
});
```

And following is the html code:

```
<mysection folder-name="sections" template-url="headerSection"></mysection>
```